# C# MVC Executar Função (LogOut) Ao Fechar o Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou em um sistema de atendimento e necessito de uma ajuda para entender como eu posso chamar algum evento (Javascript / jQuery / Ou não) no momento em que um usuário fecha o navegador sem efetuar um logout "correto" pelo sistema...

Att.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar a função [unload()](https://api.jquery.com/unload/) do **jQuery** para capturar o momento que o **browser** é fechado, e a partir deste momento, você realiza uma chamada via `ajax` para a `Action` desejada. 
Antes, você verifica se o navegador foi atualizado ou fechado de vez.

Ficaria assim o código:

```
<script>
            (function ($) {
        var refreshKeyPressed = false;
        var modifierPressed = false;

        var f5key = 116;
        var rkey = 82;
        var modkey = [17, 224, 91, 93];

        //Verifica se submit
        var submitting = false;
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            submitting = true;
        });

        // verifica as chaves de atualização
        $(document).bind(
            'keydown',
            function (evt) {
                // busca por atualização
                if (evt.which == f5key || window.modifierPressed && evt.which == rkey) {
                    refreshKeyPressed = true;
                }

                // checa se há modificação
                if (modkey.indexOf(evt.which) >= 0) {
                    modifierPressed = true;
                }
            }
        );

        // verifica as chaves de atualização
        $(document).bind(
            'keyup',
            function (evt) {
                // verifica a chave
                if (evt.which == f5key || evt.which == rkey) {
                    refreshKeyPressed = false;
                }

                // checa se há modificação
                if (modkey.indexOf(evt.which) >= 0) {
                    modifierPressed = false;
                }
            }
        );
        $(window).bind('beforeunload', function (event) {
            var message = "not refreshed";

            //submit é falso, realiza ação
            if (!submitting) {
                //Se atualizou entra aqui
                if (refreshKeyPressed) {
                    message = "refreshed";

                    //retorna a mensagem apenas para testes
                    event.returnValue = message;
                    return message;
                }

                //Senão, chama a action
                //$.ajax({
                //    url: BASE_URL + 'Testes/Aqui',
                //    type: 'POST'
                //});

                event.returnValue = message;
                return message;
            }

        });
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

O `script` está auto explicativo, mas uma breve explicação:
Primeiro ele filtra os possíveis eventos de atualização, como **F5**, etc. Após isso, verifica se o **submit** de sua `view`. Se não se encontrar em nenhuma desas cláusulas, ele chama a sua **action** via `ajax` .

Exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ritcheyer/8LR9f/).

Referências:

[SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008032/ajax-call-issue-on-browser-tab-close),
[Soen²](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207387/detecting-closing-tab-or-browser-script-not-working)

Comment: Randrade, eu tentei isso. Porém o _unload_ também é chamada no momento de um _refresh_, logo fica meio "inválido" a ação...

Answer (score 3):

Acrescente no seu script:

```
   window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return "Você realmente deseja fechar?";
    };
```

Comment: Talvez não me fiz claro, mas na realidade eu gostaria de chamar uma Action do MVC para efetuar o logout do usuário, até para poder registrar no banco de dados esse horário de "saída" do usuário, entende...

Comment: entendi, vou dar uma pesquisada, porque talvez tenha que usar o setTimeOut, vou ver, um momento

Comment: Ok. Na empresa aonde eu trabalho há um sistema que ao fechar o browser, uma nova janela é aberta e ocorre a limpeza de sessão e é fechada logo em seguida, tudo automaticamente! :O

Comment: e você não consegue manipular a limpeza dessa sessão, aproveitar a sessão e fazer o logout do usuário ?

Comment: Thiago, você se refere ao Session_End do Global.asax?

Comment: @AntônioFilho exatamente.

Comment: Então, eu até tentei, mas o problema é que tenho que recuperar o id do usuário logado no cookie (AuthenticationForms) para então gravá-lo no banco de dados... E até onde eu sei, o Session_End não é certeiro de sua execução... Obs: Não sei se é uma boa prática eu ter propriedades de conexão ao banco na minha Global.asax.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29176/discussion-between-thiago-friedman-and-antonio-filho).

Answer (score 1):

Não existe uma forma 100% confiável de fazer isso como em um sistema desktop, uma alternativa no ambiente web é utilizar o evento `unload()` que *desexibe* a página, com alguns filtros fica próximo do desejado.

Estava com esse problema semana passada encontrei esse código.

Basicamente o que ele faz é verificar se o ponteiro do mouse está fora da área da pagina e filtra algumas teclas para não executar a ação.

```
$(window).on('mouseover', (function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}));
$(window).on('mouseout', (function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
}));
function ConfirmLeave() {
    return "";
}
var prevKey="";
$(document).keydown(function (e) {            
    if (e.key=="F5") {
        window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
    }
    else if (e.key.toUpperCase() == "W" && prevKey == "CONTROL") {                
        window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;   
    }
    else if (e.key.toUpperCase() == "R" && prevKey == "CONTROL") {
        window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
    }
    else if (e.key.toUpperCase() == "F4" && (prevKey == "ALT" || prevKey == "CONTROL")) {
        window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
    }
    prevKey = e.key.toUpperCase();
});
```

O código foi tirado de: [SOen - Trying to detect browser close event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26275621/1342547)

Comment: rray, testei esse trecho de código no Chrome, e ficou idêntico a um 'onbeforeunload' normal... :S

Comment: @AntônioFilho no firefox tbm?

Comment: Desculpa a eternidade em responder. Mas fiz algumas alterações neste método e tals, mas ainda não é possível capturar o Ctrl+W, Alt+F4 ou comandos para sair da janela do browser. A minha intenção não é nem questionar o usuário ao fechar o browser, mas sim "executar um simples alert', ou seja, detectar o momento em que as teclas Ctrl+W são acionadas, mesmo que exiba o alert e logo em seguida feche o browser.